# Google Analytics - Two codes for one website based on language

Tags: google-analytics

I have the below code in my header:-

```
if ($_SESSION['lang'] == 'us') { ?>
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
  ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-2', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
<?php } else { ?>
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
<?php } ?>
```

So depending on which language of the site you are using, a different UA code is used.

It's all working but on Google Analytics I get the following error message:-

Tracking Code Mismatch
Tracking code on page www.xxxxxxxxxx.com does not match property XXXX Website's tracking ID UA-xxxxxxxxx-1.

Any ideas how I can sort this?

Comment: As a side-note, you don't need the conditional around the entire JS block- you could just set a variable for the tracking ID or wrap the "create" line in a conditional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @GreatBlakes - this has resolved the problem:-

```
//Analytics tracking for US
$language = $_SESSION['lang'];
if ($language == 'us') { 
    $UA_CODE = 'UA-XXXXXXXX-2'; //USA
} else {
    $UA_CODE = 'UA-XXXXXXXX-1'; //UK
}
?>
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
  ga('create', <?php echo $UA_CODE; ?>, 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```